# No longer valid vs. Invalid

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

There is a subtle or perhaps more than subtle difference between the phrases **"no longer valid"** and **"invalid"**. Can English experts elaborate with examples where one should be used and not the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Invalid** means that something is not valid.

**No longer valid** means that something was valid in the past, but that is no longer the case.

Something that is no longer valid, is currently also invalid, but something that is invalid has not necessarily ever been valid.

Basically it is the same difference as when I say:

> This door is painted red.
>   This door is no longer painted blue.

Both door are not blue, but the second one *used* to be blue.

Now, if a user fills in something in a form, say an email address, and the email address he fills in is "bbdgfjj", we can say the entry is invalid. It never was valid, so we cannot say it is no longer valid.

If the user fills in "someone@example.com", possibly that is a valid entry. If at some point, "example.com" goes out of business, the email address is *no longer valid*.